# How to serve static files in Node.js using Hono.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hono

I am using Hono.js for Node.js to build an API. And for serving static file I am using `serveStatic` middleware.

```
user.use("/static/*", serveStatic({ root: "./" }));
user.get("/signin", serveStatic({ path: '../public/signin.html'}));
```

I also tried this -

```
user.get("/signin", serveStatic({ root: "./", rewriteRequestPath: (path) => path.replace(/^\/signin/, '/public')}));
```

The `signin.html` file in under `public` directory in the `root` dir. When I am sending a text or json using `c.text` or `c.json`, the expected output is shown. Which implies that routing is correct.

But using this code, the output is

```
<-- GET /user/signin
--> GET /user/signin 404 9ms
```

Any idea how to solve this ? How to serve files or send files as a response to any request ?

Comment: _"But it is not working"_ isn't really enough information to help

Comment: try this https://hono.dev/getting-started/nodejs#rewriterequestpath

Comment: @UmerAbbas I tried. I am feeling something is missing somewhere. But I do not know what. Edited the question for you.

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar problem on my end

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that by default the `serveStatic` middleware would match the pat h starting from the current directory (where the hono app was started).

I have my hono app setup like so:
[image]

And I have the following directory structure:
[image]

Notice the `static` folder at the project root.

So that when a request hits up `/static/file.json` it'll return the file located at the same path.

Here's the end result (if you've got everything setup correctly):
[image]

Comment: please replace images of code with the actual text used?

Comment: please add the filename that has the server static function